# Why binary.Read() doesn't work for struct?

Tags: go, struct

I'm a beginner of golang

and my golang version is 1.13

I try to use `binary` package as follow

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/binary"
    "fmt"
)

type Coordinate struct {
    x float64
    y float64
    z float64
}

func (self Coordinate) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("(%f,%f,%f)", self.x, self.y, self.z)
}

//not work
func test() {
    var point Coordinate = Coordinate{1, 2, 3}
    buf := bytes.Buffer{}
    binary.Write(&buf, binary.LittleEndian, &point)
    fmt.Println(point)
    fmt.Println(buf)

    p := new(Coordinate)
    //panic: reflect: reflect.flag.mustBeAssignable using value obtained using unexported field
    binary.Read(&buf, binary.LittleEndian, p)
    fmt.Println(p)
}

func main() {
    test()
    println("over")
}
```

and I got error message like this:

```
panic: reflect: reflect.flag.mustBeAssignable using value obtained using unexported field
```

It's there anything wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error says it all: you can't use unexported fields. Change the fields of `Coordinate` to be exported:

```
type Coordinate struct {
    X float64
    Y float64
    Z float64
}
```

Then it'll work, and outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/cELBd55Rqw_w)):

```
(1.000000,2.000000,3.000000)
{[0 0 0 0 0 0 240 63 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 64 0 0 0 0 0 0 8 64] 0 0}
(1.000000,2.000000,3.000000)
over
```

Also never omit errors in Go. [`binary.Read()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/#Read) and [`binary.Write()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/#Write) return errors, always check them, for example:

```
if err := binary.Write(&buf, binary.LittleEndian, &point); err != nil {
    // Handle error, for brevity we just panic here:
    panic(err)
}

if err := binary.Read(&buf, binary.LittleEndian, p); err != nil {
    // Handle error, for brevity we just panic here:
    panic(err)
}
```